# VirtualBox and Solidworks license manager

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd, license, solidworks

I'd like to install Solidworks license manager in a VirtualBox guest (Win7 Pro) - not Solidworks itself, just the licensing server. However, I get this error:

"Activation license mode is not supported in this virtual environment.  You may continue the installation, but activation will fail"

Searching for a solution, I came across this promising thread:
https://serverfault.com/questions/727347/solidworks-activation-license-mode-is-not-supported-in-this-virtual-environment

My question is: Is there a similar workaround for VirtualBox? The host is FreeBSD 10.4-STABLE

Comment: VirtualBox is not really in the same class as KVM, VMware, or the other high-production hypervisors. VirtualBox DOES have very extensive and exhaustive documentation. So, have you looked through the documentation to see if this is noted as possible/impossible?

Comment: Have you looked at this question: https://superuser.com/questions/625648/virtualbox-how-to-force-a-specific-cpu-to-the-guest

Comment: @music2myear VirtualBox is a type-2 hypervisor which is the same type as Hyper-V (Windows 10) or VMWare Workstation.  The authors real question is indeed how to change the cpuid of the vm so the hardware (VM) check passes.

Comment: Anyways the linked question, at Serverfault, has the required VirtualBox commands you need to run.